# How to use multiple groupby statements in Entity Framework linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I have a table with these columns:

```
POS
CropName
productionQty
```

I have to find `POS` containing the crops with higher quantity.

I have tried

```
  from r in await _crops.GetAll()
  group r by r.CropName
  into g
  select new
         {
             id = g.Key,
             sum = g.Sum(r => r.productionQty),
             name = g.First().PosName,
             cropname = g.First().CropName,
         };
```

I have got all crop quantity but I need crop according to POS containing higher quantity.

```
   Example:
   PosName productionQty CropName
    POS1     100         Crop1
    POS2      200        crop2
    Pos1     300         crop1
    pos1     200          crop2
```

I want following result:

```
    PosName productionQty CropName
    POS1     400         Crop1
    POS2     200        crop2
    pos1     200          crop2
```

Comment: `higher quantity` what does that mean? do you mean you want to SORT?

Comment: can you provide example data for this?

Comment: Have a look at the question. I have edited the question

Comment: The example result just shows the example data grouped by `PosName, CropName` pair with summed `productionQty`, is this what you are looking for? If yes, just look at the LINQ docs/examples of grouping by composite key.

Comment: We don't understand your request because "higher" is a word for making comparisons, for example you can say "the price of this TV is higher than that TV". You can't say "what is the higher price out of these five TVs costing 100, 200, 300, 400, 500?" because 200 is higher than 100, and 300 is higher than 200 and 100. There are too many numbers that are "higher" than another number. "Highest" price is 500, and there is only one price that is highest, but "higher" needs something to compare it to to make sense, like "how many TVs have a price 'higher' than 250?"

Answer (score 0):

Just going off your "desired result" it looks like you perhaps want to change the line:

```
group r by r.CropName
```

To

```
group r by r.CropName.ToLower() +'\n' + r.PosName.ToLower()
```

This means case will be ignored and the result where there are two rows that have pos1/crop1 will be combined but the other rows that are pos1/crop2 and pos2/crop2 will be separate

You should bear in mind that it might not produce exactly the result you want, because what you get for PosName and CropName will depend on what element ends up first in the result group list. These things are grouped case insensitive so a list of `pos1, POS1, PoS1` grouped and first()'d would return pos1, but the list `POS1, pos1, PoS1` would return POS1